# Glassfish Authentication - How to use my own login method

Tags: jakarta-ee, authentication, glassfish, glassfish-3

I am really new to this. Here's what I want to achieve:

The user types in his user name and password from login web page, my code will check our database. If the username and password (stored in one table) is correct, and if the user belongs to certain group (stored in another table), then I will allow the user to login.

I know Glassfish comes with several autentication realms: file, ldap, jdbc...

How do I incorporates my code with its autentication realms? Is there a tutorial or step by step guide that I can follow?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the provided Java EE security implementations, you can use third party libs like Apache Shiro, which offer role based access control (RBAC) and authentication.

http://shiro.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

beside all the third parties authentication mechanism , you can also provide your own authentication mechanism handled by GlassFish server. JAAS is form based authentication which you can use(as JAAS can also provide some other type of authentication mechanism).The mechanism that I am purposing you is like

**HTTPRequest for some application
 ->
(redirect to) LoginAuthenticationApp 
->
(if authorized then)
 -> 
requested App 
->
 (else) Login App**
 
Now here is the thing , By using JAAS mechanism after login all of your request(each and every httprequest) will be provided by Glassfish server as you defined by your authentication jar.

*Another thing* that you can seperate your login APP or place it in your any/every applicaion.
By placing it seperatly, its functionality would be to read the request , authenticate from DB and redirect to the request application by setting that cookie(in case you use cookie).
Another good reason which I found is that all requests will be go to that login app  and to the actual app which prevents any type of DOS attack.
here you can find the [Customize container-managed security](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-authenticroast/index.html?ca=drs-). I always recommend to use container-managed securities for applications which needs high security or which have DOS threats.